Run page as create mode BC AL
Help. I added a get() set() procedure in my Purchase Header to predefine and access some variables, and i need to run set() before opening a page. How to do so but page is open in create mode?
I saw Yun Zhu's post about but this it doesn't quite work for me since it inserts the record first, not an ideal behavior my user wants. They want an identical flow like purchase order line to purchase order (card)....
Thank you in advance.

Please add some code samples of what you have tried so far e.g., the content of your Set() and Get() procedures, triggers on page/pageextention etc.
